# Deployment of smart contract on remix again & again state varables get back to initial state

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, remix, ganache

I am working on a web based DApp.

My question is, everytime when I have to work on project I am deploying a smart contract on remix & each time the variables of smart contract gets back to initial state which is technically correct as I am deploying again and again.
but as a product it must preserve its state so, how that can be done?? can it be resolved with truffle and ganache??

Comment: You will face the same issue with truffle but, truffle enables you to run test scripts or any scripts you need whenever your want. So, you are able to inject data in your smart contract to carry on your devs.

Comment: Thank You @EmmanuelCollin! Do you know how to resolve this problem? or can you mention someone?

Comment: Ganache + truffle + custom script to inject your data after every deployment

Comment: OKay I will try this but can you explain about that custom script or share any resource/blog ??

Comment: Look at the [truffle exec](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands#exec) command to execute any js script you want/need. You can use this way to connect to your deployed smart contract and load data into it.

Comment: I will try truffle and ganache.